# characteristic function properties

Tags: characteristic-functions

In lecture, we had the following corollary (without proof, unfortunately):
If $ A \in (0,2) $ and $X$ is a random variable (real-valued) with the following characteristic:

$$ \mathbb P(X > x) = \mathbb P(X < -x) = \frac{x^{-A}}{2} \text{ for any } x \in [1, \infty).$$

Then, the following is valid as $t \to 0$:

$1-\phi(t)\sim C|t|^A $, where $\phi$ is the characteristic function and $\displaystyle C = \int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos(u)}{u^{A+1}} \, du$.

Why is this correct? Can somebody show me?

Comment: I'm guessing ~ means $\frac{1-\phi(t)}{C|t|^A} \to 1$ as $t \to 0$?

Comment: Yes it does. But why is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $X$ is symmetric hence $1-\phi(t)=E[1-\cos(tX)]$, that is, 
$$
1-\phi(t)=\int_1^{+\infty}(1-\cos(tx))\frac{A\mathrm dx}{x^{A+1}}=A|t|^A\int_{|t|}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(u)}{u^{A+1}}\mathrm du,
$$
thanks to the change of variable $u=|t|x$. The last integral converges when $t\to0$ because $A\lt2$ and at $+\infty$ because $A\gt0$ hence the result holds with
$$
C=A\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(u)}{u^{A+1}}\mathrm du.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explication!

Comment: Maybe one last question:
If $G_n = X_1 + ... + X_n $, why does $ n^{\frac{-1}{A}} G_n $ converge in distribution to a random variable?

Comment: Other question $\implies$ other post.

Comment: Ok, I have done.